# How to remove the button border in css? border:none is not working

Tags: html, css, button, border

Can anyone help me I can't remove button border. border:none; is not working

```css
button {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: white
  border: none;
}

button:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow! , please provide the example or working demo

Comment: FYI, you're missing a `;` (semicolon) in line before the `border:none` rule. Fix that first, if it works, you can close the question.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. Please also read [why an image of your code is not acceptable](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you are missing ; in the line before.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please read [answer]. The question is clearly caused by a typo. As such, such questions should not be answered. They should be commented instead and flagged as `not reproducible or caused by typos`. As those question hold no value to the SO community they will closed and removed. All awarded points reverted.